# VB.NET Compare two string for full or partial match

Tags: string, vb.net, compare

How do you programmatically Compare two string for full or partial match.

I may have a string called "ItemName" like "003.00.112.0" and a string I am trying to compare it to the string named "ItemNameToFind" like "001.*.*.**.*" where " * " is meant to be an unknown blank spot.

What I have figured out so far is that it's some sort of an if statement that needs to correctly compare the strings.

```
If ItemName = ItemNameToFind Then
    MsgBox("Item " & ItemName & " was found based on " & ItemNameToFind)
End If
```

In the example above it would return that it's not a match because of the first three symbols in the string.

Could, someone, please, help with the code to make that happen correctly as I explained?

Comment: Vb has a like operator and .net has a Regex class, and your question is to vague to go beyond that.

Comment: My question is very much specific and with provided example and explanation

Comment: Like mentioned in the example "*" is a blank / unknown segment that could be anything. I can define the length of each unknown segment if that's necessary.

* = any zero or more characters

Comment: It looks like you would find regular expressions useful. There are lots of tutorials available, e.g. [RegexOne](https://regexone.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VB.NET you can use the [`Like` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator):

```
 Dim ItemName = "001.00.112.0"
 Dim ItemNameToFind = "001.??.???.?"

 If ItemName Like ItemNameToFind Then
     Console.Write("Item " & ItemName & " was found based on " & ItemNameToFind)
 Else
   Console.Write("not found")
End If
```

Note that i have replaced your `*` with `?` since that means "Any single character".

```
?   Any single character
*   Zero or more characters
#   Any single digit (0–9)
[charlist]  Any single character in charlist
[!charlist] Any single character not in charlist
```

Comment: Thank you very much good sir! So I get that I need to specify the number of unknown symbols using "?" instead of "*" for any number of characters?

Comment: Yes, if you use `*` it means that it can be "zero or more characters".

Comment: Yup, but it would still work, right?

Comment: @Eduards: Yes, but it would be less strict.